# How to build resolution independent website?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

How to write html code that will be resolution independent and it will show the same in any resolution and any pc monitor size. 
I am using  Asp.net

Comment: U can use http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: you should see responsive web design.you can use bootstrap css,Foundation css for responsive application.

Comment: Why you say "show the same size", do you mean show the same percentage of the screen (e.g. fill 3/4 of the screen)?  Or literally measure the same size on each screen (e.g. be three inches across on all screens) whether it's a smartphone screen or a 54" monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **responsive web design**.There are few possible ways to do it. You can select according to your need

> 1. You can use media queries in which you define different stylesheets for different screens. This is the most used way currently. 
>    Sneak Peek:
>      http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and
>      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
> 2. You can use the viewport meta tag. 
>    Sneak Peek:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
> 3. You can design everything in % (fluid responsive) but that part is very tricky. From my experience I can say that designing a full
>      website giving everything in % is very difficult.

I will suggest you to learn media query. Its quite simple and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

For different desktop resolutions, there a responsive type called as **Fluid responsive** Where you assign almost all element size in **percentage %**.